# Cannot authenticate to exchange 2007 with suds

Tags: python, exchangewebservices, suds

I am using suds 0.4.1 with exchange 2007 and basic authentication.  I get a 401 error even though I can login with those credentials through a browser.  Here is my code:

```
from suds import *

c = client.Client(url='path_to_wsdl', username='my_username', password='my_password')
```

And here is the exception I am getting:

```
Suds EWS error: suds.transport.TransportError: HTTP Error 401: basic auth failed
```

Comment: Are you sure Basic works?  Probably NTLM.  If you have access the server via regular http, and not just SSL, then you should be ale to see the Authorization headers.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use an NTLM transport object.

Examples here: http://blogs.oucs.ox.ac.uk/inapickle/2011/05/14/exchange-web-services-suds-and-python/

I haven't really gotten it to work for myself either but I've managed to get past the 401 errors.